# Error: POI 3.16 in android studio ignoring innerclasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Tags: android

I searched for many solutions for my problem but it didn't work

I tried lots of things in proguard-rules.pro but it didn't work

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keepattributes InnerClasses

-dontoptimize

-dontwarn InnerClasses

-dontoptimize

-optimizations !code/allocation/variable

**build.gragle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.incarb.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-collections4-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/curvesapi-1.04.jar')
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-3.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-examples-3.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-excelant-3.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-scratchpad-3.16.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')

}
```

**Error Log:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.RussianDollStrategy$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.util.Type$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.jam.JamUtils$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$SchemaTypeLoaderCache$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$ThreadedReader$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCodeGenerator$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaResourceManager$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XsbDumper$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.validator.ValidatingXMLInputStream$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpathgen.XPathGenerator$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/ReferenceResolver;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLEvent;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLInputStream;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLName;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLStreamException;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable$Util;
Error:8 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.77 secs
Information:10 errors
Information:30 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Thanks for trying to help me :)